# browser() debug statement R

Tags: debugging, r, browser

I have an R script where I have inserted the following code:

```
options(Debug=TRUE)
#SOME MORE CODE
browser(expr = isTRUE(getOption("Debug")))
#SOME MORE CODE
```

After the debugger starts, I would like it to proceed to the next line so I type `n`.  However, this does not proceed to the next line but rather seems to continue.

How do I step through the remainder of my code after a `browser()` statement?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To set a point within a function at which to begin debugging, you'll likely want to use `trace()`.

Let's say you have a function `myFun` and want to begin debugging it right before its call to `plot()`:

```
myFun <- function() {
    x <- 
        8:1
    y <- 
        1:8
    plot(y~x)
    lines(y~x)
    text(x,y, letters[1:8], pos=3)
}
```

To construct the call to `trace`, you will need to know **at which step** in `myFun` the call to `plot()` occurs. To determine **that**, use the construct `as.list(body(myFun))`:

```
as.list(body(myFun)) 
# [[1]]
# `{`
# 
# [[2]]
# x <- 8:1
# 
# [[3]]
# y <- 1:8
# 
# [[4]]
# plot(y ~ x)
# 
# ... More ...
```

After noting that the call to plot occurs in step 4, you can use `trace()` to tell R that you'd like to enter a browser right before step 4 every time `myFun` is called:

```
trace(myFun, browser, 4)

# TRY IT OUT
# (Once in the browser, type "n" and press Enter to step through the code.)
myFun()
```

Finally, when you're done debugging the function, turn the trace off with a call to `untrace(myFun)`.

---

**EDIT**: The strategy for setting breakpoints for sourced-in scripts is similar. Again, you don't actually insert code into the script. Instead use `findLineNum()` and `setBreakPoint()`.

Let's say that the function `myFun()` described above is defined in the text file `"myScript.R"`, which has five blank lines before the function definitions. To insert the breakpoint right before the call to plot:

```
source("myScript.R")            # Must source() once before using findLineNum 
                                # or setBreakPoint
findLineNum("myScript.R#10")    # I see that I missed the step by one line
setBreakpoint("myScript.R#11")  # Insert the breakpoint at the line that calls 
                                # plot()

myFun()                         # Test that breakpoint was properly inserted
                                # (Again, use "n" and Enter to step through code)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I am not trying to debug a function but rather a pretty long script (maybe it should be modularized a bit).  For functions I have been ok doing `debug(myFun)`, and that seems to work.  However, I would like a way to set a breakpoint in my script and step through my code after that break point...

Comment: There, I added an example that shows how to set a breakpoint in a script. Nicely, as with the call to `trace`, you don't actually need to insert any code in your definition of the function in the script file. Cheers!

Comment: Josh, thanks for the answer.  How do I set the break point without first sourcing my entire script? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Alex -- To insert debugging code in a function, R needs that function to have been read into the current R session (so that it exists!), so I'm pretty sure there's no way around `source()`ing in at least the function you want to debug.  The easiest way may be to break out the function to be debugged into its own source file; then you will only need to source in that one bit of your code in order to debug the function. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

`browser()` is generally for use when running in interactive mode and used in a sub function because if you have it inline in a script and source the whole thing in it will simply execute the next line against the browser prompt when it is called.

E.g. assuming the script:

```
options(Debug=TRUE)
browser(expr = isTRUE(getOption("Debug")))
b <- 1 
b <- 2
b <- 3
```

It would execute like this:

```
R> options(Debug=TRUE)
R> browser(expr = isTRUE(getOption("Debug")))
Called from: top level 
Browse[1]> b <- 1 
Browse[1]> b <- 2
Browse[1]> b <- 3
```

If you were to run the script step by step and then call a function as so then it's use makes more sense:

```
R> options(Debug=TRUE)
R> a <- function() {
 browser(expr = isTRUE(getOption("Debug")))
 b <- 1
 b <- 2
 b <- 3
 return(b)
}
R> e <- a()
Called from: a()
Browse[1]> n
debug at #5: b <- 1
Browse[2]>  # ENTER
debug at #6: b <- 2
Browse[2]> b
[1] 1
Browse[2]>   # ENTER
debug at #7: b <- 3
Browse[2]> b
[1] 2
Browse[2]>   # ENTER
debug at #8: return(b)
Browse[2]> b
[1] 3
Browse[2]>   # ENTER
[1] 3
R>
```